# Ubuntu crashed during an update

Tags: 20.04, updates, crash

I updated from `20.04` to `20.10`, and during the `installing updates` phase, the system crashed.

Is there a way to just update the Ubuntu files, without editing /home? I have a backup from a bit ago but its slightly outdated so wouldn't want to use it.

The system thinks it's 20.10

Comment: If your system is running, I would login to a text terminal (not GUI if it's a desktop; you didn't say) and `sudo apt update` to read messages & ensure all looks good, then assuming it's as expected (ie. *groovy* and no *focal*) I'd `sudo apt full-upgrade` to try and let the install/upgrade continue. Once it's completed (assuming no issues), then I'd reboot & try and login normally. If you get messages/errors, they'll provide a clue as to what needs to be done, but hopefully it'll continue with what I've described without any more.  (*data not backed up can't be that important*)

Comment: dpkg: error processing package
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration

\n

errors were encountered while processing:
  libavcodec58:1386

Comment: If you have additional details, please add them to your question. I'd read the messages around it looking for clues (does the version of it match what should be there for your soon to be *groovy* system, what appeared before that; any clues there, or anything inappropriate in the first `sudo apt update` I mentioned for starters). We can't read those messages so are limited. You can of course `sudo apt -f install` to try and fix, OR do what it suggests and `install --reinstal` but I'd verify the messages & versions in those messages first (ie. messages are there for a reason)

Comment: Ok so its a GUI version, and i've tried doing `sudo apt install update` and that errors. It `apt-get`s the update fine, but can't install them

Comment: The messages provide the clues; assuming you upgraded with `do-release-upgrade` you should have no *focal* sources visible in the `apt update`; so do the versions match *groovy*, ie. 7:4.3.1-4ubuntu1 (ie. read the messages we cannot see & verify they are what they should be). For us to help, we need the messages (added to your question as I've already alluded to).